# Incremental counter right before each <br />

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This should be easy, although I spent over 4 hours and nothing! I REALLY need to add a counter for `<br />` tag, inside an specific DIV CLASS, to count lyric lines, and "echo" the corresponding number on each line right before the `<br />`. I understand that this can´t be done by css, like happens with `<p>`, because `<br />` won´t allow before and after css conditionals. Will really appreciate the help.

Example:

Every time when I look in the mirror 1

All these lines on my face getting clearer 2

The past is gone 3

And it went by, like dusk to dawn 4

Isn't that the way? 5

Everybody's got their dues in life to pay 6

Yeah, I know nobody knows 7

Where it comes and where it goes 8

I know it's everybody's sin 9

You got to lose to know how to win 10

Comment: Did you try putting the lyrics in an array and then loop through them? Print the lines while looping and set a counter variable. Increase the counter by 1.

Comment: show what you have attempted (show your code)

Comment: please post the HTML rather than just the text. a CSS counter could be used if you modify the HTML and wrap each line within a div (or other) element

Comment: I have the following code, not working. True beginner :)

<?php
$lyrics = "<p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br />All these lines on my face getting clearer <br /> The past is gone <br /> And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br /> Isn't that the way? <br /> Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br /> Yeah, I know nobody knows <br /> Where it comes and where it goes <br /> I know it's everybody's sin <br /> You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>";

$arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $lyrics);

foreach($arr as $index=>$ele){
echo $ele . $index+1 . "<br />";
} ?>

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use explode function to extract all new lines as below

```
$arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $lyrics);

foreach($arr as $index=>$ele){
echo $ele.$index+1.'<br>';
}
```

If you are getting another issues please fill free to comment.

Comment: That would be great, but I am getting an error from the PHP editor on line: echo $ele.$index+1.'<br>';

Comment: Ok, I have this, not sure what is missing :p <?php $lyrics = "<p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br />All these lines on my face getting clearer <br /> The past is gone <br /> And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br /> Isn't that the way? <br /> Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br /> Yeah, I know nobody knows <br /> Where it comes and where it goes <br /> I know it's everybody's sin <br /> You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>"; $arr=explode(PHP_EOL, $lyrics); foreach($arr as $index=>$ele){ echo $ele . $index+1 . "<br />"; } ?>

Comment: $arr=explode("<br />", $lyrics);
foreach($arr as $index=>$ele){
echo '<p>'$ele.$index+1.'</p><br/>';
}

Answer (score 0):

If each line is a `<p>` you can do that to replace each `<br>`

```js
var listElements = document.getElementsByTagName('br')

for(var i = 1; i <= listElements.length; i++){    
var line = listElements[i-1].parentElement.innerHTML

    listElements[i-1].parentElement.innerHTML = line.replace('<br', i+'<br')
}
```

```html
<p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br /> </p>
    <p>All these lines on my face getting clearer <br /></p>
    <p>The past is gone <br /></p>
    <p>And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br /></p>
    <p>Isn't that the way? <br /></p>
    <p>Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br /></p>
    <p>Yeah, I know nobody knows <br /></p>
    <p>Where it comes and where it goes <br /></p>
    <p>I know it's everybody's sin <br /></p>
    <p>You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>
```

Comment: I only have the <p> for each paragraph, not each line. All the content is inside a variable, showing like this: <p>Every time when I look in the mirror <br />
   <p>All these lines on my face getting clearer <br />
 The past is gone <br /></p>
And it went by, like dusk to dawn <br />
Isn't that the way? <br /></p>
Everybody's got their dues in life to pay <br />
Yeah, I know nobody knows <br />
Where it comes and where it goes <br />
I know it's everybody's sin <br />
You got to lose to know how to win <br /></p>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the numbers of any tags from simple javascript code.

```js
let countbr = document.getElementsByClassName('count-br')[0].getElementsByTagName('br').length; 
console.log('Total </br> count on class count-br: ',countbr);
```

```html
<div class="count-br">
  This page has 4 br
  </br>
test
</br>
test test test
</br>
</br>
</div>

<div class="donot-count-br">
  This section has 3 br
  </br>
test
</br>
test test test
</br>
</div>
```